# angular md-sidenav don't appear correctly

Tags: angular, angular-material

When I open a sidenav in `over` mode I don't see the grey background like the [sidenav example](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview). If I click outside the sidenav, it doesn't close.

In my project, the md-container is the wrapper for the content and the `md-sidenav` is in `<div class="card">`.
(inside my sidenav I have a timeline with some notes)

I am using angular material `2.0.0-beta.11`.
Whats wrong with this code?

```html
<at-sidenav-container>

<div class="main-content">
<mat-sidenav position="end" mode="over" #sidenav>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="card card-plain">
            <div class="card-content custom-timeline">
                <ul class="timeline timeline-simple">
                    <li class="timeline-inverted"
                        *ngFor="let note of ticketBundleNoteList">

                        <div class="timeline-badge success">
                            <i class="material-icons">description</i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="timeline-panel">
                            <div class="card-row">
                                <div class="card-row-content padding-right10">
                                    <i class="material-icons">account_circle</i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-text card-row-content">
                                    <div class="timeline-heading">
                                        <h3>Nome</h3>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="timeline-body">
                                        <p>{{note.text}}</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-footer">
                                <div class="stats">
                                    <span> <i class="material-icons">update</i>
                                        {{'cardfooter.inserteddate' | translate }} {{note.createdDate
                                        | date :('pattern.datehourmin' | translate)}}
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
</mat-sidenav>
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">

                <div class="card" *ngIf="selected">
                    <div class="card-header card-header-icon"
                        data-background-color="main-theme-color">
                        <i class="material-icons">work</i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-content">
                        <form #modelForm="ngForm">
                            <h3 class="card-title">{{
                                'ticketbundle.detail.titles.header' | translate }}</h3>



                            <div class="row">

                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="form-group label-floating">
                                        <label class="control-label">
                                            {{'ticketbundle.detail.labels.customer' | translate }}</label>
                                        {{selected.customer.name}}
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="form-group label-floating">
                                        <label class="control-label">
                                            {{'ticketbundle.detail.labels.city' | translate }}</label>
                                        {{selected.customer.city}}
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="dropdown col-md-2 col-md-offset-2">
                                    <button type="button"
                                        class="btn btn-round btn-info dropdown-toggle pull-right"
                                        data-toggle="dropdown">
                                        <i class="material-icons">build</i> <span class="caret"></span>
                                    </button>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
                                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Audit log</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Snapshot</a></li>
                                        <li (click)="openSidebar()">Open sidenav</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="row">

                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="form-group label-floating">
                                        <label class="control-label">
                                            {{'ticketbundle.detail.labels.landlinephone' | translate }}</label>
                                        {{selected.customer.landlinePhone}}
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="form-group label-floating">
                                        <label class="control-label">
                                            {{'ticketbundle.detail.labels.email' | translate }}</label>
                                        {{selected.customer.email}}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">

                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="form-group label-floating">
                                        <label class="control-label">
                                            {{'ticketbundle.detail.labels.from' | translate }}</label>
                                        {{selected.startDate | date :('pattern.date' | translate )}}
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="form-group label-floating">
                                        <label class="control-label">
                                            {{'ticketbundle.detail.labels.to' | translate }}</label>
                                        {{selected.endDate | date :('pattern.date' | translate )}}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-pills-info">
                                        <li class="active"><a href="#ticketBundleRow"
                                            data-toggle="tab">{{
                                                'ticketbundle.detail.titles.ticketbundlerow' | translate }}</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#busRouteDetail" data-toggle="tab">{{
                                                'ticketbundle.detail.titles.busroutedetail' | translate }}</a></li>
                                    </ul>

                                    <div class="tab-content">
                                        <div class="tab-pane active" id="ticketBundleRow">
                                            <p-dataTable [value]="ticketBundleRowList"
                                                sortField="fareTypeName" [responsive]="true"
                                                resizableColumns="true" [sortOrder]="1" [immutable]="false"
                                                reorderableColumns="true"> <p-column
                                                field="fareTypeName"
                                                header="{{ 'ticketbundle.detail.ticketbundlerows.table.labels.faretype' | translate }}"
                                                [sortable]="true"></p-column> <p-column field="ticketQty"
                                                [sortable]="true"
                                                header="{{ 'ticketbundle.detail.ticketbundlerows.table.labels.ticketqty' | translate }}"></p-column>
                                            <p-column field="unitPrice" [sortable]="true"
                                                header="{{ 'ticketbundle.detail.ticketbundlerows.table.labels.unitPrice' | translate }}">
                                            <ng-template let-col let-unitPrice="rowData" pTemplate="body">
                                            <span> {{unitPrice[col.field] | currency:'EUR':true}}
                                            </span> </ng-template></p-column> <p-column field="totalPrice" [sortable]="true"
                                                header="{{ 'ticketbundle.detail.ticketbundlerows.table.labels.totalPrice' | translate }}">
                                            <ng-template let-col let-amount="rowData" pTemplate="body">
                                            <span> {{amount[col.field] | currency:'EUR':true}} </span> </ng-template></p-column></p-dataTable>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="tab-pane" id="busRouteDetail">

                                            <p-dataTable [value]="busRouteDetailList" sortField="name"
                                                [responsive]="true" resizableColumns="true" [sortOrder]="1"
                                                [immutable]="false" reorderableColumns="true">
                                            <p-column field="name"
                                                header="{{'ticketbundle.detail.busroutedetail.table.labels.buslinename' |
                            translate }}"
                                                [sortable]="true"></p-column> <p-column field="stopName"
                                                header="{{'ticketbundle.detail.busroutedetail.table.labels.busstop' |
                            translate }}"
                                                [sortable]="true"></p-column> <p-column
                                                header="{{'ticketbundle.detail.busroutedetail.table.labels.day' |
                            translate }}">
                                            <ng-template let-day="rowData" pTemplate="body">
                                            <span class="selectedDays" *ngIf="day.mon == true">{{
                                                'weekday.mon' | translate}}</span> <span *ngIf="day.mon != true">{{
                                                'weekday.mon' | translate}}</span> <span class="selectedDays"
                                                *ngIf="day.tue == true">{{'weekday.tue' | translate
                                                }}</span> <span *ngIf="day.tue != true">{{'weekday.tue' |
                                                translate }}</span> <span class="selectedDays"
                                                *ngIf="day.wed == true">{{'weekday.wed' | translate
                                                }}</span> <span *ngIf="day.wed != true">{{'weekday.wed' |
                                                translate }}</span> <span class="selectedDays"
                                                *ngIf="day.thu == true">{{'weekday.thu' | translate
                                                }}</span> <span *ngIf="day.thu != true">{{'weekday.thu' |
                                                translate }}</span> <span class="selectedDays"
                                                *ngIf="day.fri == true">{{'weekday.fri'| translate }}</span>
                                            <span *ngIf="day.fri != true">{{'weekday.fri'|
                                                translate }}</span> <span class="selectedDays"
                                                *ngIf="day.sat == true">{{'weekday.sat'| translate }}</span>
                                            <span *ngIf="day.sat != true">{{'weekday.sat'|
                                                translate }}</span> <span class="selectedDays"
                                                *ngIf="day.sun == true">{{'weekday.sun' | translate
                                                }}</span> <span *ngIf="day.sun != true">{{'weekday.sun' |
                                                translate }}</span> </ng-template></p-column> <p-column field="since"
                                                header="{{'ticketbundle.detail.busroutedetail.table.labels.from' |
                            translate }}"
                                                [sortable]="true"> <ng-template let-col
                                                let-date="rowData" pTemplate="body"> <span>
                                                {{date[col.field] | date :('ticketbundle.table.pattern.date'
                                                | translate )}} </span> </ng-template></p-column> <p-column field="until"
                                                header="{{'ticketbundle.detail.busroutedetail.table.labels.to' |
                            translate }}"
                                                [sortable]="true"> <ng-template let-col
                                                let-date="rowData" pTemplate="body"> <span>
                                                {{date[col.field] | date :('ticketbundle.table.pattern.date'
                                                | translate )}} </span> </ng-template></p-column></p-dataTable>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <br> <br>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <h3>{{ 'ticketbundle.detail.titles.payment' | translate }}</h3>
                                </div>



                                <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-8">

                                    <button class="btn btn-info btn-round pull-right"
                                        (click)="newPayments()" rel="tooltip" data-toggle="modal"
                                        data-target="#paymentsModal"
                                        title="{{'ticketbundle.detail.tooltips.add' |
                            translate }}">
                                        <span class="btn-label"> <i class="material-icons">add</i>
                                        </span>
                                    </button>

                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <p-dataTable [value]="paymentList" sortField="createdDate"
                                [responsive]="true" resizableColumns="true" [sortOrder]="-1"
                                [immutable]="false" reorderableColumns="true"> <p-column
                                field="createdDate"
                                header="{{ 'ticketbundle.detail.payment.table.labels.createddate' | translate }}"
                                [sortable]="true"> <ng-template let-col
                                let-date="rowData" pTemplate="body"> <span>
                                {{date[col.field] | date :('pattern.datehourmin' | translate )}}
                            </span> </ng-template></p-column> <p-column field="currencyDate" [sortable]="true"
                                header="{{ 'ticketbundle.detail.payment.table.labels.currencydate' | translate }}">
                            <ng-template let-col let-date="rowData" pTemplate="body">
                            <span> {{date[col.field] | date :('pattern.date' |
                                translate )}} </span> </ng-template></p-column> <p-column field="amount" [sortable]="true"
                                header="{{ 'ticketbundle.detail.payment.table.labels.amount' | translate }}">
                            <ng-template let-col let-unitPrice="rowData" pTemplate="body">
                            <span> {{unitPrice[col.field] | currency:'EUR':true}} </span> </ng-template></p-column> <p-column
                                styleClass="col-button"> <ng-template
                                let-model="rowData" pTemplate="body">

                            <div class="text-center">

                                <button class="btn btn-simple btn-danger btn-icon remove"
                                    rel="tooltip" (click)="delete(model._links.self.href)"
                                    title="{{'ticketbundle.table.tooltips.delete' | translate }}"
                                    data-placement="left">
                                    <i class="material-icons">close</i>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            </ng-template> </p-column> </p-dataTable>


                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group label-floating">
                                        <md-form-field> <textarea mdInput
                                            placeholder="{{ 'ticketbundle.detail.labels.note' | translate }}"
                                            rows="4" name="notes" #note></textarea> </md-form-field>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </form>

                        <br> <br> <br>
                        <div class="card-footer">
                            <app-card-footer-cmp [selected]="selected"></app-card-footer-cmp>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <!--card  content-->
                </div>

                <!--card -->
            </div>
            <!-- md 8 -->
            <!-- row -->
        </div>

    </div>
    <!-- container-fluid -->
</div>
<!-- main-content --> </mat-sidenav-container>


<div class="modal fade" id="paymentsModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
    aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content" *ngIf="payment">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                    aria-hidden="true">
                    <i class="material-icons">clear</i>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">{{'ticketbundle.detail.payment.dialog.title'
                    | translate }}</h4>
            </div>
            <form #rowForm="ngForm">
                <div class="modal-body">

                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <md-form-field> <input mdInput [min]="minDate"
                                (click)="Picker.open()" [max]="maxDate"
                                [(ngModel)]="currencyDate" name="currencyDate"
                                [mdDatepicker]="Picker" required
                                placeholder="{{ 'ticketbundle.detail.labels.from' | translate }}">
                            <md-datepicker-toggle mdSuffix [for]="Picker"></md-datepicker-toggle>
                            <md-datepicker #Picker></md-datepicker> </md-form-field>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-md-4">

                            <div class="form-group label-floating">
                                <md-select required
                                    placeholder="{{ 'ticketbundle.detail.payment.dialog.labels.paymenttype' | translate }}"
                                    [(ngModel)]="payment.paymentType" name="paymentType">
                                <md-option *ngFor="let payment of payments"
                                    [value]="payment.value"> {{ payment.label }} </md-option> </md-select>

                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"> <i
                                    class="material-icons">euro_symbol</i>
                                </span>
                                <div class="form-group label-floating">
                                    <label class="control-label">{{
                                        'ticketbundle.detail.payment.dialog.labels.amount' | translate
                                        }}<span class="star">*</span>
                                    </label> <input [(ngModel)]="payment.amount" pattern="\d+(\.\d{1,2})?"
                                        required class="form-control" id="amount" name="amount">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="row"></div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="category form-category">
                            <span class="star">*</span> {{ 'form.requiredfields' | translate
                            }}
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <span>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-round"
                            (click)="save()" data-dismiss="modal"
                            [disabled]="rowForm.form.invalid || rowForm.form.pristine">
                            <span class="btn-label"> <i class="material-icons">check</i>
                            </span>{{'ticketbundle.detail.payment.dialog.save' | translate }}
                        </button>

                    </span> <span>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-round" data-dismiss="modal">
                            {{'ticketbundle.detail.payment.dialog.close' | translate }}</button>
                    </span>

                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what you mean by clicking outside the `side-nav` it is not closing?

Comment: If you see the example when sidenav is open the background is grey and if you click on this grey the sidenav closes, Im my project I don't see the backgroud grey and sidenav remains open

Comment: Don't wrap the `md-sidenav` in a div.

Comment: @Edric So the md-container and the md-sidenav needs to be the most external tag?

Comment: @Alessandro Why don't you show the whole code? I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: So where's your `md-sidenav`? It's supposed to be in the `md-sidenav-container`.

Comment: @Edric yes sorry I try to put it inside main content and also outside